# CI Server for .NET : Jenkins or Buildbot?

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, jenkins, buildbot, ci-server

what is pros and cons to use buildbot or Jenkins in a .NET environment ?

Regards,

Florian

Answer (score 0):

I've had very positive experience with Jenkins. Easy to install and use through the web Ui. The only thing that's been troubling me lately is VCS integration. Most of the time something to do with authentication to the repository server and SSL stuff that is supported differently on Windows than on Linuxes and similar.
The crowd behind Jenkins is big and lots of blogs and other resources are available.

As far as .NET is conserned... I've uised it with msbuild and powershell/[psake](https://github.com/psake/psake). In both cases it worked just fine. If any issues occurred they were usually related to .NET framework issues, SDKs or some such.